# Assign string values to a NSArray - iOS

Tags: objective-c, string, nsarray, assign

I have an iOS app which downloads/parses strings from a JSON file. I need to store these strings in ONE NSArray. But every time I try I get the error:

```
expected method to write array element not found on object of type 'nsarray *'
```

All I am doing is assigning these strings to the array in a for loop.... And yet it won't work. It is baffling me why... I have assigned strings and variables to an array in C and C++.... Surely Objective-C supports this as well. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my simple for loop:

```
for (int loop = 0; loop <= [youtube_channel_id_tags count]; loop++) {

    self.getYTIcon = [[YTICONGET alloc] init];
    NSString *temp_url = [self.getYTIcon get_user_icon:youtube_channel_id_tags[_carousel.currentItemIndex]];
    youtube_user_icons[loop] = [temp_url description];
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Try "NSArray" not "nsarray", Objective-C, C, and C++ are all case sensitive!

Comment: @trumpetlicks Yes I have defined my array as "NSArray".

Comment: BTW - your `loop` variable should be `NSUInteger`, not `int`.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah right, thanks. Its weird, the example in my Objective-C/Cocoa book say to use int....

Comment: `int` will generally work but since `NSArray count` and all of the other index related methods to `NSArray` use `NSUInteger`, it is more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`youtube_user_icons` needs to be a `NSMutableArray` so that you can change its contents and the line

```
youtube_user_icons[loop] = [temp_url description];
```

needs to be

```
[youtube_user_icons addObject:[temp_url description]];
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your `youtube_user_icons`type? Should be `NSMutableArray*`, not `nsarray *`!